# How to access javascript object inside another object

Tags: javascript, json, object, restangular

`enter code here`How to access objects in Javascript
[This is the Object trying to Access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRt33.png)

[This is the Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sq9uq.png)

Its returning 'UNDEFINED' why?
It may be silly. please help me im new.

CODE :

```
    app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope,Restangular) {
      Restangular.setBaseUrl('http://localhost:8080/StrutsREST/api');
      var arr=Restangular.all('interfaces').doGET();
      var obj=arr.$object;
      console.log(obj.A1);  
    });
```

Comment: What do you receive with `console.log(obj)`?

Comment: Please post code as code, not as a screenshot

Comment: it displays UNDEFINED. And when I try Convert Object to Array It Returns a Empty Array

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you are doing API call which is async you need to handle it as Promise by using .then statement

```
Restangular.all('interfaces').getList().then(function(data) {
    console.log(data.A1);
})
```